# How many numeric strings of length 8 have exactly three 9's OR exactly three 8's (or both)?

Tags: combinatorics

I need help with a question: 
How many numeric strings of length 8 have exactly three 9's OR exactly three 8's (or both)? 
Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, but would you mind at least shedding some light on any thoughts you've had about the problem so far?

Comment: Are you able to get the answer if the requirement is just for, say, exactly three $9$'s? Or would you also need help with that?

Comment: I've been thinking to add up C(8,3) twice for strings that have three 9's or 8's in it, but I'm not sure how to do both.

Comment: Can you counte the strings that have exactly three 9's ?

Comment: I think strings that have exactly three 9's should be C(8,3), but I'm not absolutely positive.

Comment: You have to multiply the number of ways of choosing the positions of the $9$'s by the number of ways of filling the other five positions in the string.

Answer (score 1):

$S_9$, cases with exactly  $3\; 9$s, will contain $S_{8,9}$, 
cases with exactly $3\; 8$s and  $3\; 9$s, and  $S_8$, cases with exactly  $3\; 8$s, will  also contain $S_{8,9}$. So you will want to find $$\#(S_9)+\#(S_8)-\#(S_{8,9})$$ for your final answer, to avoid double-counting $S_{8,9}$.

I'll work out $\#(S_{8,9})$, the number of cases wheres you have exactly $3\; 9$s and exactly $3\; 8$s, then you should be able to work out the remaining sets.

So choose the position of the $3\; 9$s, ${8 \choose 3}$ options, then choose the position of the $3\; 8$s, ${5 \choose 3}$ options, then choose the occupants of the remaining $2$ slots, which can be any of the other $8$ digits, since a numeric string can have leading zeroes - $8^2$ options. This gives $$\#(S_{8,9}) = {8 \choose 3}{5 \choose 3}8^2 = 56\cdot 10\cdot 64 = 35840$$

Now you can find $\#(S_{9})$ (and $\#(S_{8})$ has the same value of course).